# Tensorflow Saved model inference results differ on the same input

Tags: tensorflow, inference

I have trained a model am trying to get correct predictions. But everytime i run predict i get a different result on the same inputs. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Tried on tensorflow 2.13.0 and 2.14.0 the model was trained on a GPU, and am inferring on CPU.

The model i am loading is a wide resnet model that i have trained

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
 input (InputLayer)          [(None, 160, 160, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 WRResNet (Functional)       (None, 27, 27, 256)       4304960   
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d (  (None, 256)               0         
 GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                         
                                                                 
 dropout_9 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0         
                                                                 
 prediction (Dense)          (None, 15)                3855
```

Sample loading code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("saved_model.pb")
test = np.ones((1, 160, 160, 3), dtype=np.float32)
for _ in range(2):
    out = model.predict(test)
    print("Empty", out)
```

Samples output:

```
Empty 1.7617911e-05 ...

Empty 2.2262917e-05  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was caused by how i created the model.

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(160,160, 3), name="input")
wr_model = get_wr_model()
model_out = wr_model(inputs,True)
preds = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_labels, activation="softmax", name="prediction"
        )(model_out)
...etc
```

While if i change the way i consume the model to

```
inputs = wr_model.input
model_out = base_model.output
```

The model becomes deterministic on prediction